# How to remove the stale gitk-tmp file?

Tags: git, version-control, git-bash, gitk

I'm getting the error shown on the image below after running `gitk` command on *Git Bash* shell and browsing my diffs on gitk gui tool.

[image]

The problem is that I can't find the stale **gitk-tmp** file this dialog is referring to. I've looked for the path `~/.config/git/gitk-tmp` both on the project root folder and on the *Git Bash* installation folder, but couldn't find it in any of these locations.

I've also configured hidden folders to be shown on windows explorer to make sure that I would see them if they were hidden, but also with no luck. For example, there's a hidden folder called `.git` inside the project root folder, but there's no "gitk-tmp" file inside it either.

Could anyone please give me a hand on finding and removing this "gitk-tmp" file so that the error shown in the image won't happen anymore? Thanks.

Comment: "~" means home directory, so it should mean "%HOME%\.config\git\gitk-tmp", if you have the environment variable HOME defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As max630 mentioned, `~` means the home directory on your machine.

Such as if you are using windows OS, then you should go to `C:\Users\username\.config\git`  directory to find the `gitk-tmp` file and delete it. And make sure the  `C:\Users\username\.config\git` directory only has the file `gitk`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Marina. I will accept your answer but with just one remark: I had to delete both `gitk` and `gitk-tmp` files. When I delete only `gitk-tmp` file, I start to get another ugly error, but deleting both files solves everthing. I think these two files are somehow syncronized by "Git for windows", and that's probably the reason why they need to work as a pair.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays I don't use gitk anymore, having thus replaced its usage by Tortoise for Windows. I still use git bash because I like to type git commands and see them on the command prompt rather than using a GUI tool.

So, kind of a work around for my original question, after three years of stumbling with this problem I don't face it anymore because I think it's more productive to use a combination of git bash to write git commands + Tortoise Git to view file diffs and resolving merges.